# wget can see the internet, ping and git cannot

Tags: networking

This is on a virtual CentOS host which I access via terminal ssh, and have sudo rights on.

`wget` works fine. Neither `ping` nor `git` can see the internet at all. Since `wget` is able to resolve host names while fetching pages, it doesn't seem to be DNS related.

I checked the iptables command as suggested below; no relevant protocols seem to be blocked.

How do I go about troubleshooting the cause?

Comment: What protocol are you trying when using git? If I remember correctly, git can work over at least ssh or http(s). Looking at the firewall (`sudo iptables --list`) could be helpful, filtering outbound connections is rare but could happen. Wireshark can be a friend of yours, it will capture the entire traffic over the network interface.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I've tried with http://, https://, git://, and ssh://. Just checked the iptables, doesn't seem to be blocking anything but tcp.

Comment: Having DNS is not an indicator of having external access. Is wget able to fetch a page?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Yes, `wget` is able to fetch pages.

Comment: If in a corporate setting, this is due to firewall rules. talk with your network team

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Ah, I had looked for similar questions, but didn't find that one. That does look like it might be the same issue; I'm working through the answer now to see what it reveals.

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable IPV6 on all interfaces and check again. Also make sure to check what DNS resolution brings? IPV4 or IPV6?  , use `nslookup` or `dig` commands.

You can also use `tracepath` or `traceroute` to make sure the destination is reachable or not , something on your network , or outside firewall may have blocked such traffic like `ICMP` packets.

Can you successfully do a `curl www.google.com`

But , to me the issue seems to be firewall related , if not on that machine , may be some other firewall in your path to destination. ( For testing , disable firewall service completely for a moment and try again , if it is just a test machine , rebooting will fix it for sure :) )